# Tampermonkey to access a JSON call/URL on a page?

Tags: javascript, json, userscripts

I have a page `index.html` which calls an external URL. This external URL is a JSON endpoint. In other words, I see two resources when I open DevTools (with <kbd>F12</kbd>): `index.html` and `myJSONEndpoint`.

I want to be able to grab that JSON each time I load `index.html` and do something with it.

Would Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey be able to achieve this?

Page example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Weather</title>
  <script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.weather.gov/points/39.7456,-97.0892", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Page Loaded...</p>
</body>

</html>
```

When I load that page, two requests appear in DevTools. Base index page and the JSON request.

I want to grab the JSON content and push it onto the DOM. The User can then copy/paste from there.

Comment: Yes, Tampermonkey can do that. But this question is way to broad; you need to provide details and either a link to the page or a [mcve].

Comment: Added sample to my answer

Comment: If you want to save a file, your options are limited.  You can use either [Tampermonkey's GM_download function](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_download), send the data to your own webapp, or try the deprecated FileWriter API (Chrome only)..

Comment: OK, so perhaps it's easier just to grab the JSON content and push onto the DOM? User can then copy/paste from there. I'm not precious about the downloading part. Create a new `<div>` then stick the contents in there? Struggling to see how I grab the URL and content of the JSON call. Could I be cheeky and ask for a sample script?